# Capture currently running programs as start-up programs

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I remember in previous versions of Ubuntu there used to be a feature to capture currently running programs, and automatically set them as start-up programs. In 12.04 I can't find this feature anymore.
Is it still available?
There is a way to manually add start-up programs, but I would like to use the automatic feature that used to be available in other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using verion 11.04 or previous you can do that by going to System menu -> Preferences -> Startup Applications -> Options Tab, and here you can check the "Remember currently running applications".

BUT if you're using a newer version (11.10 or newer) that option does not exist anymore, and no plans to implement in the near future due to numerous side effects.

So because you're using 12.04 I think that's not possible. I'm not sure about KDE.

Also if you still want to manually add application to startup just check [here - Ubuntu 12.10](http://imacify.com/2012/11/how-to-add-application-to-the-startup-on-ubuntu-12-10/)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding the programs the manual way.